# trying to convert a pb model to a tflite model. it keeps saying it has loaded assets to path but the folder is empty

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook

code used in jupyter notebook

[image]

I expected to see a `tflite` file inside model 3 but there was nothing. extensions used are:

```
python 3.10
tensorflow 2.8
keras 2.8
matplotlib 2.7
numpy 1.25
```

I've tried to also use this code:

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("./models/3")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

but to no avail